# Removing commas at the beginning of a line in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a CSV file from a dynamically generated table.I have a code which generates a reasonable CSV.The output of the code is

```
, Emp I D, Emp Name, Emp Title,
, 111 , andro1 , developer ,
, 112 , andro2 , developer ,
, 113 , andro3 , developer ,
```

I would like to remove the commas at the beginning of each line so the csv is well formatted.I also would like to neatly format this CSV so that it opens properly in excel(with heading in bold ,well spaced coulmns etc).

I am pasting the sample javascript used by me

```
  //Modify the value of these variable for your coach
  var tableIdsToExport = "Table0";  

  // a comma delimited list of the ids of the tables that you want to include in the excel export
  // if you include a tableId that does not exist in your coach, you will recieve a client side error message


  //You do not need to modify the following part of the script

  var form = document.createElement('div');
  form.innerHTML = '<form name="exportData" method="post" target="_new" action="data-redirect.jsp"><input type="hidden" name="contentType" value="text/csv"><input type="hidden" name="data" value=""><input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="filename=reportData.csv"></form>';
  //Work around a bug in IE: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/927917
  document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].appendChild(form);
  //document.body.appendChild(form);

  function addExportData(csvTable) {
     if (document.forms.exportData == null || document.forms.exportData.data == null) {
         return;
     }
     document.forms.exportData.data.value = document.forms.exportData.data.value +
        "\n\n" + csvTable;  
  }
  function doSubmitExport() {
    var tableArr = tableIdsToExport.split(",");
    for (var i=0;i<tableArr.length;i++) {
      addTableToCSV(tableArr[i]);
      alert(addTableToCSV(tableArr[i]));
    }
    document.forms["exportData"].submit();
  }

  function addTableToCSV(tableId) {
    var table;

    try {
      table = document.getElementById(tableId);

      var a = table.innerHTML;

      //replace existing commas with semi-colons. Poor mans way of handling embedded commas in a csv file
      a = a.replace(/,/g, ";");

      //get rid of javascript blocks
      a = a.replace(/<script(.|\n)*?<\/script>/gi, "");

      //insert commas at the end of a table cell
      a = a.replace(/<\/td>/g, ",");
      a = a.replace(/<\/TD>/g, ",");
      a = a.replace(/<\/th>/g, ",");
      a = a.replace(/<\/TH>/g, ",");

      //insert a newline tag at the end of every row. Need to do this before removing all tags
      a = a.replace(/<\/tr>/g, "---newline---");
      a = a.replace(/<\/TR>/g, "---newline---");

      //remove html tags
      a = a.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");

      //remove whitespace (regexs found via google)
      a = a.replace(/\r/g, " ");
      a = a.replace(/[^ A-Za-z0-9`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)-_=\+\\\|\]\[\}\{'";:\?\/\.>,<]/g, "");
      a = a.replace(/'/g, "");
      a = a.replace(/ +/g, " ");  
      a = a.replace(/^\s/g, "");
      a = a.replace(/\s$/g, "");    

      //put newlines in
      a = a.replace(/---newline---/g, "\n");

      //replace &nbsp which the coach designer inserts
      a = a.replace(/\&nbsp;/g, " ");

      //a now holds a resonable csv that I can put in excel
      //alert(a);
      addExportData(a);
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      alert("Table Export Error: " + e);
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

One more thing is, in the table there is a column which is empty.that is the reason that the script is returning a comma at the beginning which I would like to remove.
when I try to open the csv in excel the content starts at the third row instead of the first row.

This is being used in IBM BPM Lombardi application where I am trying to export a a dynamically generated table to excel.

I would also like know how the same result can be achieved through jquery
Thanks in advance

Once this is done I am also planning an export to pdf option.

the following expalins what is being done in the script

The key component that performs the export is a Custom HTML code block that contains client-side JavaScript. The JavaScript contains the following components:

1.A JavaScript variable tableIdsToExport. This is a comma-delimited string that itemizes the table element ids to be exported. You must ensure that the ids match those in your Coach.

2.A JavaScript variable form that is a dynamically generated HTML form element (not displayable). The URI for the action attribute of this form is a Teamworks JSP that will return the spreadsheet. This form also contains an input field data that contains the table(s) to be exported.

3.An 'Export to excel' button. When this this button is selected the doSubmitExport function is executed.

4.doSubmitExport function. The algorithm for this function performs two tasks. First, it iterates over each table in tableIdsToExport and calls the addTableToCSV function. After the iteration is complete the function submits the form element contained in the form variable (above).

5.addTableToCSV function. This function is called for each table in the tableIdsToExport list and has two basic tasks to perform. First, the HTML table is transformed such that the table elements are replaced by commas and line feeds effectively transforming the table into a CSV. Next, the addTableToExport function is called with the transformed table passed as a parameter.

6.addTableToExport function. This function takes a parameter that is the CSV and appends it to the hidden form's data field.
Upon submission, the form is posted to the Teamworks data-redirect.jsp which applies the appropriate content type and sends the data back to the browser.

Comment: It would seem to make more sense modifying the CSV generation script rather than fiddling with it's output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with David Thomas, when he says that you should fix problem in the CSV generation script.

But if you don't have control over that script, you can use [regular expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) in the javascript [`replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to replace the first occurrence of a comma with an empty string (removing it):

```
", 111 , andro1 , developer ,".replace(/^,/, '');
```

that returns:

```
" 111 , andro1 , developer ,"
```

---

**Update:**

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTkwX/) you can see a demo of a javacript that removes the first comma and justifies all columns to a predefined max width.

Since you don't have a jQuery tag, I am assuming you want pure Javascript, but keep in mind that with jQuery would be much easier.

The final output you can see from the demo, is

```
     EmpID,   EmpName,  EmpTitle,          
       111,    andro1, developer,          
       112,    andro2, developer,          
       113,    andro3, developer,
```

In this case I am right justifying each column to 10 characters.

About the bold in columns title, that is not possible in CSV format, because CSV is a plain text format. You might consider for this [xlwt](http://www.python-excel.org/).

Again, I agree that you should solve this formatting problem from the generating script, but if you are just the consumer of those files and want to fix them in javascript, then this solution should work for you.

---

**Update 2**
You need to clean that javascript. Please read the regexp link that I included above.

You can replace this:

```
a = a.replace(/<\/td>/g, ",");
a = a.replace(/<\/TD>/g, ",");
a = a.replace(/<\/th>/g, ",");
a = a.replace(/<\/TH>/g, ",");
```

with simply this:

```
a = a.replace(/<\/t(d|h)>/gi, '');
```

And why are you replacing `</tr>` and `</TR>` with `--newline--` and then again you replace `--newline--` with `\n`? You could simply do this in a single call:

```
a = a.replace(/<\/tr>/gi, '\\n');
```

So, I think you end up having a single string with all csv content, where each row is separated by a `\n`.

[**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XSKHX/1/) is the updated script to handle this use case. I only changed the `var` declaration, the core remains the same.

Comment: I don't see how jQuery would help in this simple text manipulation problem.

Comment: I pointed out jQuery, because its more elegant to use selectors than using `document.getElementById` and also `each()` loops. Its kind of hard to go back to pure Javascript once you start with jQuery. But I agree that my comment about jQuery, in this specific case, maybe was pointless.

Comment: Thanks Jose.I will try this now.It would be useful for me if you could let me know how to use regular expression for each of the lines of the output CSV file.
The reason is in the javascript I am using the whole output(the csv content as a whole) is stored in a variable.I would be great if I could iterate each of the lines and apply the regular expression.
Also can you let me know how it is done in jquery.(I am pretty new to javascript and jquery)

Comment: @sathishkumar Tell me more about that variable that stores all csv content. Is it a string? If yes, what is the row separator or there is no row separator and you want to break the lines on every 3th column? Just give me an example of a real case scenario and will be glad to help you out.

Comment: @Jose-I have updated my question with the script I am using.the row seperator is a new line character \n.Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Jose-Thanks for the update.
The regular expression a = a.replace(/<\/t(d|h)>/gi, ','); is working but when I use the expression a = a.replace(/<\/tr>/gi, '\n');  to replace all <tr> an <TR> i just get an output where the entire content is displayed in a single row in MS-Excel.
Is there any better alternative to this than using the existing script?

Comment: @sathishkumar Sorry, I made a mistake. Use `a.replace(/<\/tr>/gi, '\\n')` instead (use `\\n` and not `\n`)

Comment: @jose-I tried using the updated string. the output I am getting is appended explicitly with a "\n"(which is not required) instead of a new line.

I tried using the code for formatting 
by assigning variable a to var allCsv like this  var allCsv = a;
but was getting some errors.
will an assignment like this work?

Comment: @sathishkumar You are getting a big string with a "\n" instead of a new line, and thats what is expected to happen. Now, you should split that big string on that `\n` separator, in order to get an array with the individual rows, as I did in the demo code http://jsfiddle.net/XSKHX/1/

Comment: Thanks Jose for the update.But I still have one problem.I want to take the entire output into a variable and export it, just as shown in the program above.how do I assign the entire content(document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += csv[i] + '<br />';) to a variable so that I can export it to csv.

Comment: I am not sure if you want that variable to be a string or an array of strings, so I am showing both to you (look at the very bottom of the code) http://jsfiddle.net/7E6zs/2/

Comment: Hi Jose,I added the functionality you had showed me.It doesn't seem to be working for me.the output is formatted with a line break<br>.which I am not sure will work if I save it as a csv file. I want the contents of each row of the table in a separate line which is being done in the existing script. one problem with the existing script is it is adding two blank lines at the beginning of the file so in excel the content starts from the third row(which I dont want).and as mentioned above in my question the commas at the beginning is due an empty column.

Comment: Now I want to just remove the commas at the beginning of the row.As stated the entire content is stored in a variable "a" where the formatting is required.I am just stuck here. sorry for making this long .Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not getting any commas at the beginning of the row, there is something wrong with your code. Take another look at my code, is not that hard. I found two empty lines at the end, that I removed http://jsfiddle.net/7E6zs/6/

Comment: I tried using the given code.just to see if it works I created a sample html file where I embedded javascript.I am getting an error at "document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += csv[i] + '<br />';" as "is null or not an empty object.http://jsfiddle.net/uTZPe/6/

Comment: You get a null error, because in your code, there is no element with id "output". To solve this, just put this element: `<div id="output"></div>` inside your `<body>` and it will work. Side node: You don't need to add `<html>` and `<body>` tags to jsfiddle (it automatically insert those for you behind the scenes) http://jsfiddle.net/uTZPe/7/

Comment: Thanks Jose,using the <div> element solved the issue but I am still unable to put the entire content to the variable.the output is fine in the browser,but I want the formatted output to be sent and saved as a csv file,where the entire content is stored in a variable which I am unable to do.Please help.

Comment: Do you want a String variable? If yes then do `var entireContentAsString = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML;`. If you want an Array of Strings (for each row), then `var entireContentAsArray = document.getElementById('output').innerHTML.split("<br>");`. Maybe are not understanding how split() or join() works, please google for that. I think my code is pretty clear. I don't know how to explain better than this, or maybe I am misunderstanding you.

Comment: Hi Jose,May be i am confusing you.If you see the above program there is a variable 'a' declared in the try block whose content is 'var a = table.innerHTML'.In the program above all the manipulations are done on that variable.after all the formatting the variable is sent to be stored as csv file.I am sending the content stored initially at a.Hope this helps you to understand.again when you place an alert for the variable you can see the formatting that takes place on this contentwhich is then finaly sent as a parameter to the redirect.jsp(please refer above).

Comment: Hi Jose the output is not written to the variable allContentString what might be the reason? http://jsfiddle.net/uTZPe/7/ thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Jose,
I think I confused you too much,sorry for that.anyways The code you had shown helped me to format the csv(thought what ever formatting is done on a csv it doesn't open as expected in excel).Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

And for formatting the expressions, regular expression will not come to your rescue. That formatting must be done in your CSV generation script.